# What is the difference between await functions (coroutine) and subscribe on Reactor

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Kotlin + Reactor (Mono and Flux) and I wanna know the difference between using `await...()` (from [kotlin-coroutines-reactive](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-reactive)) function and `subscribe()` (from Reactor). I brought two examples to show what I'm trying to do.

**Example 1 (with await function):**

```
@Test
internal fun test() = runBlockingTest {
    Mono.error<String>(IllegalStateException("exception"))
        .doOnError {
            print("error")
        }.awaitFirst().let {
            print("success")
        }
}
```

Output: "error" **with the IllegalStateException stack trace**.

**Example 2 (with subscribe function):**

```
@Test
internal fun test() = runBlockingTest {
    Mono.error<String>(IllegalStateException("exception"))
        .doOnError {
            print("error")
        }.subscribe {
            print("success")
        }
}
```

Output: 
Just "error".

Why example 1 shows the stack trace and example 2 doesn't show?

Thanks.

Comment: In the first example you explicitly ask for the first value with `awaitFirst` and get the exception as the answer. In the second example you don't request anything, you just subscribe and provide a callback that runs on each received item.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `subscribe` on a reactive chain you decouple it from the main flow, it becomes independent and potentially asynchronous. Error is travelling on the reactive stream as a signal rather than as a traditionally thrown exception. In this case error handling is the responsibility of the reactive chain using operators like `doOnError`, `onErrorMap`, `onErrorReturn`, etc.

On the other hand Kotlin's `await` breaks this independence and attaches the reactive stream back to the main flow and lets you write reactive/asynchronous code as it would be imperative (e.g.: try-catch blocks, unwrapped function return types, etc.).